# Uniqueness of the ternary Golay codes

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, reference-request, solution-verification, coding-theory

In [Van Lint - Introduction to Coding Theory] the uniqueness of the binary Golay codes is shown quite easily. In essence, the proof boils down to the fact that there is only one 2-$(11,5,2)$-design up to isomorphism (which is left as an exercise to the reader). In the following section on ternary Golay codes, van Lint mentions that there is not such an easy uniqueness proof as in the binary case.

I think I have found a uniqueness proof of the ternary Golay codes which is not substantially harder than that of the binary Golay codes. Please let me know if you find any flaw, or if you know a reference, where a similar proof can be found. Any feedback is highly appreciated.

---

## Prerequisite

Analogously to van Lint's proof, I will reduce the uniqueness of the Golay codes to the uniqueness of a simpler object, which in fact is very closely related to the 2-$(11,5,2)$ design used by van Lint.

**Proposition 1:**
Up to permutation of the coordinates, there is only one binary $(11,24,5)$ code containing the zero vector.

More precisely, any such code also contains the all-one-vector, 11 words of weight 5, and 11 words of weight 6. The words of weight 5 form the incidence matrix of a 2-$(11,5,2)$ design, and the words of weight 6 are just the words of weight 5, with zeroes and ones interchanged. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2613936/39281) for a construction of that design.

**Sketch of a proof:** By adding a parity bit, any $(11,24,5)$ code extends to a $(12,24,6)$ code which satisfies a certain [Plotkin Bound](https://wildonblog.wordpress.com/2011/01/16/a-proof-of-a-plotkin-bound/) with equality. Hence, the words of the extended code (using $\{\pm 1\}$ as the alphabet) are given by the rows of $\pm H$, where $H$ is a Hadamard matrix of order 12, which is very closely related to the incidence matrix of a 2-$(11,5,2)$ design.

## Uniqueness of ternary $(11,3^6,5)$ codes

Let $C \subseteq \mathbb{F}_3^{11}$ be any ternary $(11,3^6,5)$ code containing the zero vector (without loss of generality). Then $C$ is a perfect code, and it is completely routine to count the number of words of any specific weight in $C$. These numbers are given in the following table:

$$\begin{array}{r||c|c|c|c|c|c}
        \text{weight} & 0 & 5 & 6 & 8 & 9 & 11\\
        \hline
        \text{number of words} & 1 & 132 & 132 & 330 & 110 & 24
    \end{array}
$$

Since there are words of weight 11 in $C$, we may assume without loss of generality that $C$ contains the all one vector, which is denoted by $\mathbf{1}$. In the following, we call a word of $C$ of *type* $(i,j)$ if it consists of $i$ ones and $j$ twos.

**Observation 1:**
$C$ contains the negative all-one-vector $-\mathbf{1}$, 11 words of type $(5,6)$, and 11 words of type $(6,5)$, which are just the negatives of the words of type $(5,6)$.

**Proof:**
The words of weight 11 in $C$ form a binary $(11,24,5)$ code, so this is an immediate consequence of Proposition 1. $\square$

**Observation 2:** The following table lists all possible types of words of $C$, grouped by their parities (sum of coordinates).

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c}
\text{Parity } 0 & \text{Parity } 1 & \text{Parity } 2\\
\hline
(0,0), (0,6), & (0,5), (3,2), & (5,0), (2,3), \\
(6,0), (3,3), & (6,2), (3,5), & (2,6), (5,3), \\
(3,6), (6,3) & (0,11), (6,5) & (11,0), (5,6)
\end{array}
$$

**Proof:** By interchanging all zeroes and ones in the words of $C$, we get another perfect code $C'$ containing the zero vector with the same parameters of $C$. Thus $C'$ has the same weight distribution as $C$. Consequently, the only possibilities for the number of ones in any word of $C$ are 0,2,3,5,6, or 11. Since $C$ also contains the negative all-one-vector by Observation 1, we also can interchange the roles of 0 and 2 in $C$, and repeat the same argument to show that the only possibilities for the number of twos in codewords of $C$ are given by 0,2,3,5,6,11 as well. The table above just consists of all possible combinations of these numbers which add up to weights of code words of $C$. $\square$

**Observation 3:** A code word of $C$ has zero parity if and only it its weight is divisible by three. In particular, the subset $C_0 \subseteq C$ of all words of zero parity has size $3^5$.

**Proof:** Immediate consequence of Observation 2. $\square$

**Observation 4:** Let $X \subseteq C$ be the subset of words of type $(5,6)$. Then $X$ generates a 6-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{F}_3^{11}$.

**Proof:** By Proposition 1, $X$ is unique up to permutation of the coordinates. So the assertion can be checked for any concrete example, such as the one given by the Paley construction. $\square$

**Observation 5:** We have $C_0 = X^\perp$. In particular, $C_0$ is a five dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{F}_3^{11}$.

**Proof:** Let $x \in X$ be any vector, and let $D \in \mathbb{F_3}^{11 \times 11}$ be the diagonal matrix whose diagonal is $x$. Consider the code $C' = D \cdot C$. By construction, this is a perfect code with the same parameters as $C$ containing the zero vector and the all-one-vector. It contains the set $D \cdot C_0$ which consists only of words of weights divisible by three. By applying Observation 3 to $C'$, we get that all words in $D \cdot C_0$ have zero parity. But this is just a restatement of the fact that all words of $C_0$ are orthogonal to $x$. Since $x \in X$ was arbitrary, we conclude $C_0 \subseteq X^\perp$. Since, by Observation 4, $X^\perp$ has size $3^5$, these sets are indeed equal. $\square$

**Observation 6:** We have $C = C_0 \cup (C_0 + \mathbf{1}) \cup (C_0 - \mathbf{1})$. In particular, $C$ is a six dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{F}_3^{11}$.

**Proof:** By Proposition 1, any two words of $X$ have exactly two ones in common. Consequently, the inner product of any two words of $X$ is two. We conclude $X - \mathbf{1} \subseteq X^\perp = C_0 \subseteq C$, and hence $X \subseteq C + \mathbf{1}$. As before, we see that $C + \mathbf{1}$ is a perfect code containing the zero vector and the all-one-vector. Applying Obervation 1 to $C + \mathbf{1}$, we see that $X$ consists of all words of type $(5,6)$ of $C + \mathbf{1}$, and by Observation 5, we get $X^\perp \subseteq C + \mathbf{1}$. Hence, $C_0 - \mathbf{1} \subseteq C$.

We repeat essentially the same argument for the set $\mathbf{1} - X$. This set is orthogonal to $X$, so $\mathbf{1} - X \subseteq C_0$, whence $-X \subseteq C - \mathbf{1}$. The latter is a perfect code containing the zero vector and the all-one-vector, and $-X$ consists of all words of type $(6,5)$ in $C - \mathbf{1}$. By Observation 1, we get $X \subseteq C - \mathbf{1}$, and, applying Observation 5 again, we get $X^\perp \subseteq C - \mathbf{1}$. Hence, $C_0 + \mathbf{1} \subseteq C$.

This finishes the proof since $C, C_0 + \mathbf{1}$, and $C_0 - \mathbf{1}$ are disjoint sets, each of size $3^5$. $\square$

Combining Proposition 1, Observation 4, and Observation 6, we see that $C$ is generated by the incidence matrix of a 2-$(11,5,2)$ design (with zeros and twos interchanged) which is unique up to permutation of coordinates.

## Uniqueness of ternary $(12,3^6,6)$ codes

At this point, it is immediate that the parity check extension of the ternary Golay code yields a ternary $(12,3^6,6)$ code, and it is easy to show that it is essentially unique:

Let $C \subseteq \mathbb{F}_3^{12}$ be any ternary $(12,3^6,6)$ code containing the zero vector (without loss of generality). By removing any coordinate of $C$, we get a $(11,3^6,5)$ code which contains words of weight 11, but no words of weight 10. Therefore, $C$ must have words of weight $12$, and we may assume without loss of generality that $C$ contains the all-one-vector.

Now let $C' \subseteq \mathbb{F}_3^{11}$ be the code obtained from $C$ by removing the last coordinate. Let $x \in C$ be arbitrary, and let $x' \in C'$ result from $x$ by removing the last coordinate. By the previous section, exactly two of the symbols (0,1,2) occur in $x'$ in a number of times divisible by three. So $x_{12}$ must be the remaining symbol occuring in a number of times in $x'$ not divisible by three, since otherwise we can remove a specific coordinate from $x$ to obtain a different word, where the number of occurrences of at least two symbols is not divisible by three.
So $C$ must be the parity extension of $C'$.

In particular, $C$ is a linear code generated by a Hadamard matrix of order 12 (and therefore is self dual).